# ErrorException Undefined variable: toplam (View: C:\wamp64\www\laravel\resources\views\form.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

Variable toplam cannot be found

i'm using laravel latest version

HomeController like this

```
     public function get_form()
    {  
        return view('form'); 

    }

    public function post_form(Request $request)
    {  
        $bDegisken=$request->birinci;
        $iDegisken=$request->ikinci;
        $toplam=$bDegisken+$iDegisken;
        return view('form')->with('toplam',$toplam);
        
    }
```

web.php my file is like this

```
//get
Route::get('/form' , [HomeController::class, 'get_form']);

//post
Route::post('/form' , [HomeController::class, 'post_form']);
```

form.blade.php

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="birinci">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="ikinci">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
    </form><br><br><br>
    {{"sonuç"."  = ".$toplam}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. what is you `get` route which display form ? add that code

Comment: i updated and thank you

Comment: `get_form` function ? add that

Comment: `get_form` added

Comment: ` return view('form');` here you are not sending data

Comment: how can i solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have **2 option**

1st send data from `get` method

2nd make option data in view file

#### Step 1

```
public function get_form()
{
    $toplam = "";
    return view('form')->with('toplam', $toplam);
}
```

#### step 2

```php
<form action="" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="birinci">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="ikinci">
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form><br><br><br>
{{"sonuç"."  = ".$toplam ?? ""}}<< --------------- it is optional here
```

Comment: worked Thanks! Should I always use the get method when sending data?